# memory handling with dask-cuda on a windows machine

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, cupy

I am currently exploring how to handle memory in dask-cuda in order to write a function that will interpolate values along lines that cross an image.

My machine is a very basic windows 10 laptop with a single gpu (GeForce GTX 1050 4GB memory) and 16GB of RAM. I am using the following packages:

- cupy 10.2.0
- cudatoolkit 11.6.0
- dask 2022.1.0
- dask-cuda 22.2

A minimal version of my code is as follows:

```
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

from dask_cuda import LocalCUDACluster
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask import compute
from math import pi

def bilinear_interpolate(im, x, y):

    x0 = np.floor(x).astype(np.int32)
    x1 = x0 + 1
    y0 = np.floor(y).astype(np.int32)
    y1 = y0 + 1

    # keep coordinates within bounds
    x0 = np.clip(x0, 0, im.shape[1]-1)
    x1 = np.clip(x1, 0, im.shape[1]-1)
    y0 = np.clip(y0, 0, im.shape[0]-1)
    y1 = np.clip(y1, 0, im.shape[0]-1)

    # retrieve values
    Ia = im[ y0, x0 ]
    Ib = im[ y1, x0 ]
    Ic = im[ y0, x1 ]
    Id = im[ y1, x1 ]

    # calculate weights
    wa = (x1-x) * (y1-y)
    wb = (x1-x) * (y-y0)
    wc = (x-x0) * (y1-y)
    wd = (x-x0) * (y-y0)    
        
    return (wa*Ia + wb*Ib + wc*Ic + wd*Id).astype(np.float32)

# image used 5000x5000
im = cp.asarray(im)


# Set cuda-dask Client

cluster = LocalCUDACluster(
                            CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = "0",
                            device_memory_limit = 0.4, 
                            jit_unspill= True
                          )
client = Client(cluster)

# location
loc = im.shape[0] // 2, im.shape[1] //2

# radius
radius = [1,3000]

# pts per line
pts_line = radius[1]-radius[0]

# lines per degree factor
factor = 200

# radial chunks
rchunks = 180

# generate lines
r = cp.linspace(radius[0], radius[1], pts_line , dtype=np.int32)
psi = cp.linspace(0, 2*pi, 360*factor, dtype=np.float32)
R, PSI = cp.meshgrid(r, psi, sparse= True)

dR = da.from_array(R, chunks=(-1,pts_line), asarray=False).astype(np.float32)
dPSI = da.from_array(PSI, chunks=(rchunks,-1), asarray=False).astype(np.float32)

# Use polar coordinate to generate lines
rr = loc[0] + dR*np.cos(dPSI)
cc = loc[1] + dR* np.sin(dPSI)

rslt= da.map_blocks(bilinear_interpolate, im, cc, rr)

z = cp.asnumpy(rslt.compute().T)
```

I have managed, through trial and error, to interpolate +90k lines (each with 3000 points) across a single band image with 5000x5000 in size. However, as mentioned above, I am trying to write this function so that it will compute regardless of image size and number of lines to interpolate.

Much of the information I have found does not refer to windows machines (e.g. it appears that one cannot set *rmm_pool_limit* in a LocalCUDACluster as RAPIDS rmm package only works in linux). I am also familiar, thanks to the [video](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/on-demand/session/daskdistributedsummit2021-ds2105/) by Mads Kristensen, with the limitations of the *device_memory_limit* parameter (i.e., it being a soft target) and the use of *jit_unspill = True* parameter as a way to minimize GPU memory spikes, etc. Yet, despite maintaining chuck sizes way below what I have available as GPU memory, I am still running into out of memory errors.

What is the best way to determine memory requirements? I had imagine that chuck size was the most crucial aspect (I thought that regardless of the original size of the array provided the chunk size was way below GPU memory limits I would be okay).

Comment: Hi there! thanks for this question. It seems like you're dealing with some tough issues, but it would really help us out if you could post a more complete [mre] and give us a more technical/specific overview of your problem and question. We can't outline all best practices in a single answer :) For that, I can only recommend the [dask docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-best-practices.html).

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I have included a minimal reproducible example (without the image file I am using).  I am trying to be able to use this code with other images sizes, number of lines, etc but cannot figure out what parameters I should use to control GPU memory use.